# REST API to post data (images too) into mysql database using Nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, express

The below is my code which is post method to store the fields into db.But,I am getting everything undefined other than Brand id.The Brand_Image is getting stored into a folder temporaryImage.How to resolve the error

```
const createBrand = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
          console.log("inside create brand block")
          var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*9000000) + 10000000;
          var db = req.con;
          var data = {
              Brand_Id:id,
              Brand_Name:req.body.Brand_Name,
              Brand_Image:img_name,
              Sort_Order:req.body.Sort_Order,
              Status:req.body.Status
          }
          if (!req.files)
                return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
 
        var file = req.files.Brand_Image;
        var img_name=file.name;
        console.log(data)
        console.log(req.files)
         if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" ||file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ){
                                 
              file.mv('template-store/temporaryImage'+file.name, function(err) {
                             
                  if (err)
 
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        message:"Error occured",
                        err
                    })
                        var sql = ("INSERT INTO `BRANDS` SET = ?",[data]);
                          var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
                            res.json({
                                message:"Brand created successfully",
                                result:data
                            })
                       });
                  });
    }
}
    catch(error) {
        res.json({
            message:"An error occurred",
            error
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your SQL-Query causes the error.

Maybe this helps you:
[SQL- Insert Into](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)